# Is there any way to get LaTeX in OneNote?

Tags: windows

Any thoughts on how to get LaTeX in [OneNote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_OneNote)?

Comment: @Thorsten: Microsoft OneNote, the note-taking application that is part of Microsoft Office.

Comment: OneNote 2010 [has built-in support for mathematics](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/murrays/archive/2009/07/14/math-in-office-2010.aspx).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Not quite the answer you are expecting]

No, there's no way to include LaTeX (and I assume you mean the mathematics typeset with it) in OneNote.

One workaround that is sort-of-kinda-working (with severe caveats), so go ahead, if you absolutely need to. This applies to OneNote 2007, so if you have more recent version, it could be somewhat different.

1. Install the MathType Equation editor ([Wikipedia description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathtype)). It's commercial, but you can continue to use the evaluation version without LaTeX editing and other goodies for free after the trial period is over.
2. Typeset your mathematics with it (with the registered version, it understands TeX mathmode), and drag-and-drop your equations to your OneNote notebooks.

Now, the caveats:

- Formulas are read-only and appear as images. You cannot edit them once they are in place. At least they scale properly.
- The expressions are not lined with the text, so if you want to include them in a free-running text, be prepared for a major pain.

That being said, if you'd like to have a note-taking application together with LaTeX mathematics, I suggest turning to a wiki software that supports advanced typeset mathematics. I personally use [Confluence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluence_%28software%29), but free alternatives are available (the example that first comes to mind is [MediaWiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki), which powers Wikipedia, and it has comprehensive LaTeX support).

You will need to set up and administer a web server (and most likely a database server as well) in order to use wiki software, but in the long term, and especially if you are serious about having a space to collect your stuff, this is the superior solution.

Answer (score 16):

In OneNote 2010, at least (which is the only version I have), you can enter at least some LaTeX directly in math mode. I say at least some because I am discovering it by experimentation rather than reading about it in OneNote documentation (if any such documentation exists).

Here are a few examples (after first selecting the type tool and entering math mode via cmd-=):

```
\int_0^2\pi x cos(kx)dx
```

The trick with actually getting it to typeset is to hit the space bar at certain places. For instance, above, I'd hit the space bar after the `\pi` a few times, each time you'll see your equation so far getting typeset incrementally, first the integral sign then the integration bounds.

```
sin(kx)|_0^2\pi
```

There is a lot more to discover (and I am only showing a few things I have found, but I am very pleased with what I have found so far. Oh, one other item that is helpful is that you can get textbook style fraction formatting and paren or bracket resizing by hitting space after them.

Comment: Another nice thing about this setup is that you can copy the resulting typeset equations in OneNote and paste them directly into Microsoft Math and hit enter to solve. It is a nice quick way to check things when desired.

Comment: This is a great feature, horribly documented. The best documentation is this pdf (I also put the link in a separate answer): http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/redir/XT101864188.aspx

Comment: @Joe I did not understand this part: `after first selecting the type tool and entering math mode via cmd-=`. How do you enter those commands. When I enter them in onenote itself they won't change to LaTeX.

Comment: @MOON, I haven't used this in a long time, but I just booted up OneNote 2013 and I had to select to insert an equation from the Insert menu. I haven't tried this again in OneNote 2010 recently. Hope this helps.

Comment: @MOON: what he meant is to press `Alt + =`

Comment: @user21952-is-a-great-name  Link is dead. RIP. That documentation is lost forever.

Comment: @NoName The new link is https://www.unicode.org/notes/tn28/UTN28-PlainTextMath-v3.1.pdf. This was found by Ben Bolker who fixed my answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/171449/7619.

Answer (score 5):

To expand on Joe's answer, while there is no support for actual LaTeX, the LaTeX like language Joe describes is very powerful and convenient. It supports most things you'd want: matrices, subscripts, superscripts, blackboard bold, etc. The only thing I haven't been able to do are commutative diagrams with too many arrows.

Try typing this while editing text (what you'll see happening might feel confusing the first time):

```
 <Alt-=> [\matrix<space>(\doubleZ<space>&\scriptC<space>@\alpha_(0,1)<space>&1/(2\pi)<space>)<space>]<space>
```

It is pretty quick to learn, but does suffer from very obscure documentation and configuration. The best documentation I found is the pdf titled ["Unicode Nearly Plain-Text Encoding of Mathematics"](https://www.unicode.org/notes/tn28/UTN28-PlainTextMath-v3.1.pdf) (formerly linked to from a somewhat helpful [OneNote help page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/linear-format-equations-and-math-autocorrect-in-word-HA101861025.aspx)). The name Microsoft uses is "Math AutoCorrect", and the (limited) configuration is in Options -> Proofing -> AutoCorrect Options -> Math AutoCorrect tab.

Unfortunately, this type of equations is not at all supported by the online, Android or iOS OneNote.

Comment: Press `Alt + =` to enter the math mode

Comment: I am not finding any OneNote page with all the details (not even the shortcut which you have mentioned) on typing math symbols (syntaxes for symbols, shortcuts, etc.). Do you know any of the help page?

Answer (score 4):

Go here:

http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php

then type your equation and hit the Enter key. Right click on the automatically generated image and copy it into my OneNote file.

Answer (score 3):

The somewhat new OneNote for Windows 10 (the OneNote *app*) has built-in LaTeX support. To use it, write your formula out, select it, and click on Maths in the Insert tab. OneNote will then convert the formula and you will also be able to directly edit the formula.

Technically, this feature is only available if you have an Office 365 subscription, but if you disconnect your PC from the internet and start OneNote in offline mode, you will have access to the Maths feature. You can then also reconnect your PC and it won't disappear unless you restart OneNote.

This feature can also [solve an equation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/solve-math-equations-with-math-assistant-in-onenote-1b37bb8d-ecd1-40d7-8d0f-5e6e46547441?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

Comment: What is the difference to the math mode in OneNote 2010 mentioned by Joe? It sounds like it is still just a mathjax like math interpreter.

Comment: @dexteritas I don't know, could be. I just found this feature and wanted to share.

Answer (score 2):

OneNote seems to have evolved quite a bit since the question was asked. At least OneNote 2016 is somewhat capable of understanding LaTeX-like equations. It is nowhere near something like Texmaker, but its somewhere in between Microsoft Word's equation editor and Texmaker.

Click Insert->Equation or just use the shortcut (Alt+=) to type out an equation.

Comment: How does this add to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117827/? Other than saying that something which worked in 2010 works in 2016?

Comment: @cfr It still answers the original question as to how to add LaTeX equations in OneNote. And since the accepted answer seems to say that there is no way to do that, I wanted to let any new readers know that there is, in fact, a mechanism.

Comment: Of course, if the accepted answer was the only answer, this would make sense. But new readers already have this information in an existing answer. Obviously it answers the question: an exact copy of an existing answer would answer the question, if the original did. But duplicating answers just adds clutter and makes it harder for people to find the answer they need. What's wrong with the existing answer explaining how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try Alt + equal sign to activate math type box.

Answer (score 2):

This questions should be closed as no longer relevant.

Word, PPT and OneNote all support Latex both using the new equation editor or inline with 'alt+=' as of 2022.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for speed while typing up notes, the fastest I've found is the add-on [OneNote Gem](https://www.onenotegem.com/) (Gem for OneNote 2016). It's paid, some $33 when I purchased a year or two back. Gem has other features but that's the only thing I bought it for.

As others have mentioned, you use Alt + to go into math mode, so I used an AutoHotkey snippet to make this shortcut the hamburger menu button on my keyboard:

```
    #NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

; onenote set appskey/hamburger button to alt= which opens equation editor for latex input
AppsKey::!=
return
```

Once you're at the grey box that indicates you're in the equation editor, use `\TeX` followed by a space to go into Latex mode after you've got Gem installed. That makes the commands almost the same as your Latex ones, although I also sometimes still use Word's syntax for speed, e.g. `\scriptP`, and `\doubleR`.

That gets me most of the way. The main thing I haven't figured out yet is cases with a piecewise function, because `\TeX` mode breaks some things in Microsoft's native equation format.

Matrices are also a little different. I haven't gotten that to work with Word in Latex's usual commands, so I just use for instance

```
[\matrix{a&b&c@d&e&f@g&h&i}]
```

but most other things follow Latex syntax rather than Word syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using macOS, one way would be to use LaTeXit and just drag the formula inside your OneNote page. If you are using any other operating system, there are softwares like LaTeXiT in them too, or you can try using online websites.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read all this page yet, but it seems that full LaTeX support is available in Word, PowerPoint and OneNote now: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/murrays/2017/07/30/latex-math-in-office/

Comment: Hi just fired up standard one note which says what is latex and has nothing in help ? but when I ask for help on math it says buy 365 one note for office subscriptions so I guess we will never know :-)

Comment: Did you even read what you posted? It said PowerPoint and OneNote didn't support it.

Comment: @Michael it says that "it’s trickier to enable LaTeX in OneNote and PowerPoint", not completely not supported it

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround, needs MS Word though.

1. Create an equation in Word
2. Change to Latex and paste your code
3. Copy generated equation from Word
4. Paste in OneNote

Btw. if you use MathML (or converted Latex to MathML) you can paste the code directly in Word.